# Login System Not Working PHP Hash

Tags: php, hash, authentication

I am creating a login system. But for whatever reason I can't get the password to validate properly. It keeps telling me the password is wrong when I know the password is correct. Here is the form code:

```
<form id="login" action="login_processing.php" method="post">
    <label2>Email</label2>
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <label2>Password</label2>
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <a class="forgot_password" href="forgot.php">Forgot password?</a>
    <input type="submit" class="custom_submit" name="sign_in" value="Sign In">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <a href="#sliderName" class="next">Create Account</a>
</form>
```

Here the code for processing the login information on login_processing.php:

```
require_once 'database_connect.php';
session_start();

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$findLogin = "SELECT password, salt FROM client_login WHERE email = '$email';";
$loginResult = mysql_query($findLogin);
if (mysql_num_rows($loginResult) < 1){
    $_SESSION['errNo_account'] = 'No account with that email exists';
    header('Location: login.php');
}
$userData = mysql_fetch_array($loginResult, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$hash = hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password));
if ($hash != $userData['password']){
    $_SESSION['errPassword_incorrect'] = 'Incorrect Password';
    header('Location: myaccount.php');
}
else{
    $idSelect = "SELECT client_id FROM client_login WHERE email = '$email' ";
    $idResult = mysql_query($idSelect);
    while($idData = mysql_fetch_assoc($idResult)){
        $_SESSION['client_id'] = $idData['client_id'];
    }

}
```

Here is the original registration page hashing the password and adding salt:

```
function createSalt(){
        $string = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
        return substr($string, 0, 3);
    }
        $salt = createSalt();
        $hash = hash('sha256', $salt . $hash);  

    $insertLogin = "INSERT INTO client_login(email, password, salt, created) VALUES('$email','$hash', '$salt', '$today')";
    mysql_query($insertLogin);
```

It keeps telling me that my password is incorrect... when I KNOW its not. I can't seem to figure out what the error is and ITS DRIVING ME NUTS!!!

Any help would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: Try echoing your conditions in your if clause, `echo mysql_num_rows($findLogin);` see if this is returning what you are expecting.. Your first step in troubleshooting your code, is to echo everything out and ensure data is properly set

Comment: I think we need to see the code hashing the password during registration, otherwise we're only looking at one side of the equation.

Comment: @tradyblix Beat me too it; this should cause a successfull login if your passwords match? Furthermore, I would recommend looking online for tutorials for login scripts.. Yours seems... Messy, and it seems you don't fully know what you are doing

Comment: @Arms yea that was copied and pasted from an edit i created trying to test the problem I fixed to the original problem... which is "!=" and that still gives me the same issue

Comment: @arms I added the function on the create account page for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your registration script, you are using a single hash of the concated salt and pw, but in your login script you are using nested hash() calls.

registration:

`$hash = hash('sha256', $salt . $hash);`

login:

`$hash = hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password));`

notice the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Here is where I messed up.. in my haste I never actually hashed the password to begin with when creating a new account. so it wasnt hashing anything.... just itself. So I added one line (to hash the original password) in the "new account" page and that fixed the whole issue:

```
function createSalt(){
        $string = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
        return substr($string, 0, 3);
    }
        $hash = hash('sha256', $password); //this was forgotten originally :(
        $salt = createSalt();
        $hash = hash('sha256', $salt . $hash);
```

Now with that added the above code works fine. Thanks!